# Change Timestamp into shortcode Regex

Tags: regex

I am changing time stamp to shortcode i already have code.

```
$pattern = '/(\d{1,2}:\d{2}(?::\d{2})?)(?!.*?["\'])/';
$replacement = '[spp-timestamp time="${1}"]';
$foundTimestamp = preg_replace ($pattern,$replacement, $content);
```

Which is working perfect.

But i don't want select time stamps which contain am, pm

for example 01:00am or 00:01:00am and 01:00pm or 00:01:00pm

Thanks in advance.

Comment: plz add one or two sample input and output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
'~(?<!:)\d{1,2}:\d{2}(?::\d{2})?(?!(?::\d{2})?\s*[ap]\.?m\.?)(?!.*?["\'])~i'
```

Replace with `[spp-timestamp time="$0"]` where `$0` is the whole match backreference.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/DThxIn/3)

The initial negative lookbehind fails the match if there is `:` before the first 1 or 2 digits and the negative lookahead `(?!(?::\d{2})?\s*[ap]\.?m\.?)` fails the match if the time has PM or AM (with optional dots) after.

[PHP demo](http://ideone.com/qqMbde):

```
$re = '/(?<!:)\d{1,2}:\d{2}(?::\d{2})?(?!(?::\d{2})?\s*[ap]\.?m\.?)(?!.*?["\'])/i';
$str = '34:67:56  01:00am or 00:01:00am and 01:00pm or 00:01:00pm';
$result = preg_replace($re, '[spp-timestamp time="$0"]', $str);
echo $result;
// => [spp-timestamp time="34:67:56"]  01:00am or 00:01:00am and 01:00pm or 00:01:00pm
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick help :)